# use the database id as the restful service id expose a threat?

Tags: mongodb, rest

I have a restful service for the documents, where the documents are stored in mongodb, the restful api for the document is /document/:id, initially the :id in the api is using the mongodb 's object id, but I wonder deos this approach reveal the database id, and expose the potential threat, should I want to replace it with a pseudonymity id.

if it is needed to replace it the pseudonymity id, I wonder if there is a algorithmic methods for me to transform the object id and pseudonymity id back and forth without much computation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no "database id" contained in the ObjectID.

I'm assuming your concern comes from the fact that [the spec](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) lists a 3 byte machine identifier as part of the ObjectID.  A couple of things to note on that:

1. Most of the time, the ObjectID is actually generated on the client side, not the server (though it can be).  Hence this is usually the machine identifier for the application server, not your database
2. The 3 byte Machine ID is the first three bytes of the (md5) hash of the machine host name, or of the mac/network address, or the virtual machine id (depending on the particular implementation), so it can't be reversed back into anything particularly meaningful

With the above in mind, you can see that worrying about exposing information is not really a concern.

However, with even a small sample, it is relatively easy to guess valid ObjectIDs, so if you want to avoid that type of traffic hitting your application, then you may want to use something else (a hash of the ObjectID might be a good idea for example), but that will be dependent on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, Adam, and a hash of the objectID fits in my needs, and https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.node.js is a good one to follow